# Google Adsense shows up with spanish logo?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, adsense, google-ads-api

I am currently designing another website of mine and have a very weird bug, it's not required to be fixed but I am very interested on why it is happening.

I created an adsense box the same way as I always do and it works but where Google put the Adchoices logo on this design it shows up in (what I think is) Spanish (Clicking on it redirects to Googles Spanish adsense info page. The adverts displayed are in english.

The one thing that I know is different is that I am designing it using bootstrap but I have put lang='en' in the HTML Tag.

So does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

The website I am developing on is [http://pideas.rastrack.co.uk](http://pideas.rastrack.co.uk/)

Thanks - Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved somehow once I put it on the proper domain.

Answer (score 0):

have you got spanish AdSense account? i had similar issue once or twice, it was showing up in different language

Comment: Nope, Fully British account. Seems to be fixed now anyway.